# Recommendations for a ERM, DMD and ORM Diagram Creation Application for OSX

Tags: macos, orm, diagrams, dmd

I need to produce several ERM, DMD and ORM diagrams for several projects I am working on.  Obviously I'd like them to be a sleek and professional as possible, and while a simple Google search provides a plethora of options, they're all pay-for-use.

Are there any free (or open source) diagram creators available for Mac OSX which produce "sexy-enough" diagrams suitable and professional enough for use in client-accessible specification documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also [xMind](http://www.xmind.net/) it is awesome.  By far the best one I've seen - as an added benefit it is also Cross Platform.

Answer (score 2):

If you like latex, you might have a look at [pgf](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/). It generated the best looking chart I know, and the resulting files are very small.

But it does require a big learning curve and might not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about Dia? It is designed to be *similar* to Visio, although slightly less business oriented. For Mac, you can get a Darwin Ports version or compile it from source, but this isn't always easy.

You should also check this other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86234/diagram-tool-for-mac-os-x).